# Hockeyapp cURL API /new works but /upload doesn't

Tags: curl, hockeyapp

This works and uploads a new version to hockeyapp:

```
curl \
  -F "status=2" \
  -F "notify=0" \
  -F "bundle_version=version" \
  -F "bundle_short_version=short_version" \
  -F "ipa=path_to_apk" \
  -H "X-HockeyAppToken: app_token" \
  https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/app_id/app_versions/new
```

But this doesn't and throws error 422: Unprocessable entity:

```
curl \
  -F "status=2" \
  -F "notify=0" \
  -F "ipa=path_to_apk" \
  -H "X-HockeyAppToken: app_token" \
  https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/app_id/app_versions/upload
```

this also doesn't work and throws error 422: Unprocessable entity:

```
curl \
  -F "status=2" \
  -F "notify=0" \
  -F "ipa=path_to_apk" \
  -F "dsym=path_to_dsym" \
  -H "X-HockeyAppToken: app_token" \
  https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/app_id/app_versions/upload
```

- Please note I'm using a full access token
- New is properly working but I don't want to specify the bundle_version/short_version because I'm using this cURL in a cd/ci environment

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i was missing the "@" in the ipa, so even if the /new was working it wasn't uploading an actual build.

Example: @app.apk instead of app.apk